# How can I use Android Support Annotations with the Google Cloud Engine Backend w/ Messaging Module?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am attempting to use the "App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging" module with the Android Support Annotations library, per the directions here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

However, I get the error

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
```

For the following line located in build.gradle for the backend module.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
```

I am assuming this doesn't work because the module is a Java app rather than Android, but not sure how, or if, I can get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the link I provided.

The following needs to be added to the build.gradle for the backend module

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
   maven { url '<your-SDK-path>/extras/android/m2repository' }
}
```